# DynamoDB - remove from set for items based on a non-key condition

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table with the following format

- Hash Key: String
- Scopes: Set[String]
- Permissions: Set[String]

Let's define variables for the sake of simplicity:

- val scopeCondition
- val permissionToDelete

I'm trying to search for items where scopes contains the value of scopeCondition, and for those items remove from permissions the value of permissionToDelete.

As you may notice, the condition does not contain the hash key, hence my issue.
I am using scanamo as for the SDK, but I guess any solution will be easy transformed into scanamo's dsl.

Answer (score 0):

With you current schema design, you need to scan the entire table to find the records whose `Scopes` satisfy your `scopeCondition` and scan operation is the least recommended one to retrieve records from a DynamoDB table as it will increase the use of read-capacity-units very quickly with the increase in number of records in the table.

Instead, you should try to redesign your schema based on the type of queries you need to run on the table.

As described in [DynamoDB Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-concepts), NoSQL table design starts with the questions your table needs to answer and based on those questions, you decide what field should be part of Hash/Range primary key, what fields can be used to defined Global Secondary Indexes so that you can query with non-key fields of the table.

If you can elaborate on your table structure, i.e. the nature of hash key, the nature of a string value in the StringSet of `Scopes`, one can probably suggest a better design for this query.

Comment: It's a new DAL layer joining an existing one, and I have to currently save the existing scheme. It's not a big table, so maybe it won't be much of a problem to scan it though.